# create table with only header bold and center

Tags: tables

How to create a table using latex - only it's 1st row  bold and center and others are left side and normal.

```
\begin{table}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}


\caption[m1]{ m2}


\label{Hardware}\centering

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}

\hline

a & b & c & d  \\ \hline

a  & b  & c & d\\ \hline

a & b & c & d \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: the `tabular` enviroment in your MWE doesn't seem to include something that looks like a header. (The table's *caption* is not part of the `tabular` environment.) In general, you may want to use the command `\multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Table header line}}` to typeset the header line of a `tabular` environment that has four columns; "Table header line" would need to be replaced by the actual header you have in mind. Incidentally, you seem to have posted several questions but haven't accepted any of the answers provided; you may want to look into this.

Comment: I think u could't understand my question...this code will create a table....then i need to bold and center only 1st header row text..I need help for that problem ..thank u

Comment: Have you tried specifying `\begin{tabular}{llll}` to set the *overall* table alignment, as well as `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries <Header Col 1>}`, `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries <Header Col 2>}`, etc. for the entries in the first row?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Tabular does not have a concept of a header. If you want to have one, you have to modify the first row yourself. As Mico pointed out

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries <Header 1>} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries <Header 2>} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries <Header 3>} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries <Header 4>} \\ \hline
a & b & c & d \\ \hline
a & b & c & d \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Of course, this is somewhat verbose and cumbersome. Two possible simplifications:

1. First possibility: Define a macro for this

   ```
   \newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
   ```

   and then use it:

   ```
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
   \hline
   \thead{<Header 1>} & \thead{<Header 2>} & \thead{<Header 3>} & \thead{<Header 4>} \\ \hline
   a & b & c & d \\ \hline
   a & b & c & d \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
   ```
2. Second possibiliy: Alternatively, use the tabu package, which allows to specify individual row formating via the `\rowfont` command

   ```
   \begin{tabu}{|l|l|l|l|}
   \hline
   \rowfont[c]{\bfseries} <Header 1> & <Header 2> & <Header 3> & <Header 4> \\ \hline
   a & b & c & d \\ \hline
   a & b & c & d \\ \hline
   \end{tabu}
   ```

Comment: It worked.thank u..but i need to display all lines of table.In this code header lines are not display.what I need to do?                     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries h1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries h2} \\ \hline
aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb  \\ \hline
eeeeee & ffffff \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

Comment: If I try to deleting only \multicolumn{1}{c}.then lines are drowing but ,how I center only header?

Comment: @Emalka The solution is to do `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}`

Comment: @user230137 Your soulution doesn't help, because you double the '|' with every use of \thead.
So you'll get the following result:
|Header 1||Header 2|| .. ||Header n|

Comment: Didn't work for me.  The vertical lines thing is a fatal flaw.  Also, you should  use \textbf{}.

Comment: Note that as other users stated, in order to use `\thead` you need to include the package `makecell` like this: `\usepackage{makecell}`.

Answer (score 10):

With use of package `makecell` and its macro `\thead` it is simple to fulfill requested table format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
\thead{<Header 1>} & \thead{<Header 2>} & \thead{<Header 3>} & \thead{<Header 4>} \\ 
                    \hline
a & b & c & d \\    \hline
a & b & c & d \\    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Now I know why it wasn't bolded…

Answer (score 5):

To get the vertical lines in the header of the table properly aligned with the body columns, use the following:

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Header 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Header 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Header 3}
```

Comment: and if I dont want to have the vertical lines bold?

Answer (score 3):

This works with no bold lines.

`\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Header 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 3}}`

Comment: save for the probably desired \textbf{}s.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a new command like `\thead` (suggested by Tim Hoffmann) is very useful.

```
\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
```

However, if you need vertical lines the `\multicolumn` makes the command useless because you can't set the `|` manually. I've tried using optional arguments to set the text position but for some reason it didn't worked with `tabulary`.

I've achieved to center the text without `\multicolumn` (in `tabular`, `tabulary` and `longtable`) using the following two options.

1. Using `\Centering` from the package `ragged2e`, the problem is that it causes `Underfull` warnings.

```
\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\Centering\bfseries #1}
```

2. Using `\hspace*{\fill}` in both sides

```
\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\bfseries\hspace*{\fill}{#1}\hspace*{\fill}}
```

I'm currently using the second option without issues. I don't have to set the vertical lines and I can use `\bfseries`.

Comment: The optional argument doesn't work because the command becomes non-expandable, but it needs to be. If you load `xparse` and use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\thead{O{c}m}{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\bfseries #2}}`, `\thead{|c|}{bla}` will work :-) See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492145/134574

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it also works.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|l|l|l|l|},
  hlines,
  row{1} = {c,font=\bfseries},
}
a   & b   & c   & d    \\

aa  & bb  & cc  & dd   \\

aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd  \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]