# \newcommand for short notation for a \multicolumn

Tags: macros, multicolumn

Many times is handy to define `\newcommand` for short notation for `\multicolumn`. For this purposes I test two definition for such commands:

```
\newcommand\my[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\mx[2][c]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}
```

Meanwhile first definition works fine, the second throw error:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.9 \mx{A}
                &   \mx[c|]{B}  \\
```

at testing with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\newcommand\mx[2][c]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\my[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
\mx{A}      &   \mx[c|]{B}  \\
\my{c}{A}   &   \my{c|}{B}  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix definition for `\mx`?

Comment: Apparently I need an intensive course how to search for something in this site. I spend almost all my spare time in last two days and didn't discover this question/answer :-(. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\multicolumn` works by inserting an `\omit` to ignore the table column template, and it works because at the start of a table cell TeX expands tokens (thus expanding `\multicolumn`) until it finds an unexpandable token or `\omit`.

The problem is that commands defined with LaTeX's `\newcommand` aren't expandable if they have an optional argument, so TeX doesn't find the `\omit` when it's looking for one. Later, when it does find `\omit` it's too late, and you get a `Misplaced \omit` error.

Using `xparse`'s `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` you can make a command that has an optional argument *and* is expandable:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mx{O{c}m}
  {\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\my[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
\mx{A}      &   \mx[c|]{B}  \\
\my{c}{A}   &   \my{c|}{B}  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```